# Getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datetime, datepicker

I'm getting this error on my website while using the reservation form .

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>       at Function.Date.createNewFormat (jquery.stmdatetimepicker.js?ver=4.2.7:1857)
>       at Date.dateFormat (jquery.stmdatetimepicker.js?ver=4.2.7:1857)
>       at XDSoft_datetime._this.str (jquery.stmdatetimepicker.js?ver=4.2.7:1196)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (jquery.stmdatetimepicker.js?ver=4.2.7:1549)
>       at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

This is the link : [mantovacar.com/wp-content/themes/motors/assets/js/jquery.stmdatetimepicker.js?ver=4.2.7](http://mantovacar.com/wp-content/themes/motors/assets/js/jquery.stmdatetimepicker.js?ver=4.2.7)

Comment: Please produce a [mcve] so that the question can still be understood after your website has been fixed. You can use a Stack Snippet here in the editor so that the problem can be reproduced in the question itself.

Comment: i just don't know how to that, can you please help me sir ?

Comment: It's unlikely anyone can help you presently (unless they do the whole piece of work for you). You need to help people help you.

Comment: you are right , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've made debugging, and that's your problem:
`var dateTimeFormat = 'j F Y G \h i \m\i\n';`

You might want to replace `\n` with `n` at least, but this whole format seems invalid to me.

The problem occurred because the plugin creates code as sting from format and then calls `eval()` on it, which is obviously a bad practice. And when you pass `\n` as a part of your format, it gets converted to `↵` (line break). And it corrupts the code, since it's in the string, like so:

```
Date.prototype.format2 = function() { ... + '
';}
```

I would recommend you to use updated version of this library (maybe they have fixed it): https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

And consider switching to some more common date format, like `Y/m/d H:i` for example.

I couldn't find a documentation about formatting for your plugin, so you can at least check the source to see all available letters that you can use in your dateTimeFormat:

```
Date.getFormatCode = function(a) {
    switch (a) {
    case "d":
        return "String.leftPad(this.getDate(), 2, '0') + ";
    case "D":
        return "Date.dayNames[this.getDay()].substring(0, 3) + ";
    case "j":
        return "this.getDate() + ";
    case "l":
        return "Date.dayNames[this.getDay()] + ";
    case "S":
        return "this.getSuffix() + ";
    case "w":
        return "this.getDay() + ";
    case "z":
        return "this.getDayOfYear() + ";
    case "W":
        return "this.getWeekOfYear() + ";
    case "F":
        return "Date.monthNames[this.getMonth()] + ";
    case "m":
        return "String.leftPad(this.getMonth() + 1, 2, '0') + ";
    case "M":
        return "Date.monthNames[this.getMonth()].substring(0, 3) + ";
    case "n":
        return "(this.getMonth() + 1) + ";
    case "t":
        return "this.getDaysInMonth() + ";
    case "L":
        return "(this.isLeapYear() ? 1 : 0) + ";
    case "Y":
        return "this.getFullYear() + ";
    case "y":
        return "('' + this.getFullYear()).substring(2, 4) + ";
    case "a":
        return "(this.getHours() < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm') + ";
    case "A":
        return "(this.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM') + ";
    case "g":
        return "((this.getHours() %12) ? this.getHours() % 12 : 12) + ";
    case "G":
        return "this.getHours() + ";
    case "h":
        return "String.leftPad((this.getHours() %12) ? this.getHours() % 12 : 12, 2, '0') + ";
    case "H":
        return "String.leftPad(this.getHours(), 2, '0') + ";
    case "i":
        return "String.leftPad(this.getMinutes(), 2, '0') + ";
    case "s":
        return "String.leftPad(this.getSeconds(), 2, '0') + ";
    case "O":
        return "this.getGMTOffset() + ";
    case "T":
        return "this.getTimezone() + ";
    case "Z":
        return "(this.getTimezoneOffset() * -60) + ";
    default:
        return "'" + String.escape(a) + "' + ";
    }
}
```

Also, it seems like you have some issues with encoding of your js file, you should check it and switch to UTF-8, probably. But it's outside of the question scope.

For now, just change `dateTimeFormat` variable on your index page.